# Raspberry Pints will not unzip or transfer from computer

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to install Raspberry Pints and can't unzip the file. When I pull up the lxterminal it says it doesn't exist. Then when I try transferring from the computer using WinSCP I get an error code 3. Anyone else have this problem before?

Comment: Where did you save the file you need to unzip?

Comment: So please bear with me, I'm not too computer savvy as you can see. I opened my browser on the Raspberry Pi and went to the website to download it. I don't have the option to select where it goes and I don't know how to navigate to search where it went. It's on the bottom of the page and says finished "raspberrypints2.0.1.zip". Then when I open the Lxterminal it says it can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has probably ended up in the `Downloads` directory under your home directory.

1. Open up your terminal.
2. Type `cd Downloads`
3. Type `unzip raspberrypints2.0.1.zip`

Now the archive should unzip.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care where the files end up use @Bex answer but if you want them to be unzipped to a particular location I would instead recommend the following: `xarchiver ~/Downloads/filename.zip`

This will open the xarchiver utility from which you can click the extract button and then specify a filepath.